# How draw sections of stairs in autocad?

Tags: autocad, architecture

[image]

I am trying to draw a section from the front look of the unit and I am struggling with the stairs. The stairs on the plan below are located on the right side and I wish to draw the view out of them from the front view. How can I achieve this?